# How to wrap text in table with delimiter?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have one long text in a column of table. I want to wrap this it into a cell by using delimiter "/". How can I do it in `longtable`?

```
         ABCDEFGHIJ/DATSET

Format:  ABCDEFGHIJ
         DATSET
```

Comment: If you want to process a dataset freely, `datatool` package might be useful. It lets you to load a dataset with custom delimiters, and process it row by row by `\DTLforeach` command.

Answer (score 2):

Please always post a complete small document that shows the problem. (That way you typically get tested code in an answer)  But If for some reason you can't simply use a space in the source then

```
 \def\zzz#1/{\mbox{#1} }

 ....
 \z  ABCDEFGHIJ/DATSET
```

would wrap at the `/` if used in a table `p` column.